# Fail On $ grunt buildcontrol:pages jit-grunt Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, jit

Simple App with Yeoman just testing to see if I can deploy... I have run:

```
npm install grunt-build-control --save-dev

npm install jit-grunt --save-dev
```

But I get an error from the terminal saying that the plug-in can't be found? I know there may be an answer in Static Mapping just not sure how to go about it.

Here is the error from the terminal:

```
$ grunt buildcontrol:pages

jit-grunt: Plugin for the "buildcontrol" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "buildcontrol:pages" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-12-08 20:00:17 UTC)
loading tasks  288ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 99%
Total 291ms
```

And here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
    // Generated on 2015-12-08 using
// generator-webapp 1.1.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// If you want to recursively match all subfolders, use:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

  var pkg = require('./package.json');


  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Automatically load required grunt tasks

  // Configurable paths
  var config = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    config: config,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      babel: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['babel:dist']
      },
      babelTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['babel:test', 'test:watch']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      sass: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass', 'postcss']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'postcss']
      }
    },

    browserSync: {
      options: {
        notify: false,
        background: true,
        watchOptions: {
          ignored: ''
        }
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          files: [
            '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*',
            '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
          ],
          port: 9000,
          server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', config.app],
            routes: {
              '/bower_components': './bower_components'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          open: false,
          logLevel: 'silent',
          host: 'localhost',
          server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', './test', config.app],
            routes: {
              '/bower_components': './bower_components'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          background: false,
          server: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= config.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    eslint: {
      target: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
        'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },

    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
      all: {
        options: {
          run: true,
          urls: ['http://<%= browserSync.test.options.host %>:<%= browserSync.test.options.port %>/index.html']
        }
      }
    },

    // Compiles ES6 with Babel
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/scripts',
          src: '{,*/}*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/spec',
          src: '{,*/}*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/spec',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    sass: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapEmbed: true,
        sourceMapContents: true,
        includePaths: ['.']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: '.tmp/styles',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },

    postcss: {
      options: {
        map: true,
        processors: [
          // Add vendor prefixed styles
          require('autoprefixer')({
            browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR']
          })
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
        exclude: ['bootstrap.js'],
        ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
          '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= config.dist %>',
          '<%= config.dist %>/images',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles'
        ]
      },
      html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true,
          // true would impact styles with attribute selectors
          removeRedundantAttributes: false,
          useShortDoctype: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: '{,*/}*.html',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care
    // of minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not
    // wish to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            'images/{,*/}*.webp',
            '{,*/}*.html',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '.',
          src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
    // reference in your app
    modernizr: {
      dist: {
        devFile: 'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js',
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '!<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
          ]
        },
        uglify: true
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'babel:dist',
        'sass'
      ],
      test: [
        'babel'
      ],
      dist: [
        'babel',
        'sass',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    buildcontrol: {
      options: {
        dir: 'dist',
        commit: true,
        push: true,
        message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
      },
      pages: {
        options: {
          remote: 'git@github.com:adamcweitzman/portfolio-blog.git',
          branch: 'gh-pages'
        }
      },
      heroku: {
        options: {
          remote: 'git@heroku.com:example-heroku-webapp-1988.git',
          branch: 'master',
          tag: pkg.version
        }
      },
      local: {
        options: {
          remote: '../',
          branch: 'build'
        }
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'start the server and preview your app', function (target) {

    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'browserSync:dist']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'postcss',
      'browserSync:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
      grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'postcss'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'browserSync:test',
      'mocha'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'postcss',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'modernizr',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:eslint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to require 'grunt-build-control' in the Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-build-control');
```

Works fine now.